# Git remote not working after sysprepping server

Tags: windows, ssh, gitolite, openssh

So, long story short, I accidentally sysprepped my dev server not the vm I was working on (I know, too many rdp windows open and sleep deprived due to new baby).

The dev server works ok, I changed the machine name back to what it was and reassigned the old ip address. Everything else on the server seems to work but I can't connect to git anymore remotely. I assume it is gitolite or ssh related.

git clone gives me:
Connection closed by 192.168.10.20
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

This is what I get from ssh -v

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to myserver [<serveripaddress>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'myserver' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/me/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by <serveripaddress>
```

Any ideas how to fix this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any log on the server side at `/var/log/secure`?

Comment: I don't have a secure subfolder in log. The only other files in log are quite old.

Comment: ah, was logging to windows event log. "fatal: initgroups: git: Invalid argument"

Comment: Is it like in http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg82987.html? "Looking in `/etc/passwd` I see that `myid`'s `gid`, which should be the number for "`Domain Users`" listed in `/etc/group`, is a different number. Putting the correct `gid` in `/etc/passwd` fixed the problem."

Comment: That wasn't quite the problem, but I have now fixed it. The problem was that sysprep creates new machine ids so all my local Windows sids were wrong in /etc/passwd and /etc/group. Fixing these fixes the problem

Comment: Ok, I have posted an answer including your conclusion for more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit like in "[Re: sshd: PID xxxx: fatal: initgroups: myid: Invalid argument.](http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg82987.html)", the issue lies in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` having the wrong SID for the user (here '`git`')

The [OP Ian1971](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53970/ian1971) comments:

> The problem was that **sysprep creates new machine ids** so all my local Windows sids were wrong in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.